# Flurry mediation with many Ad Networks

Tags: android, flurry

hello I am implementing the flurry mediation with admob,JumpTap,Mobclix and InMobi.
And flurry mediation document says that,

```
To implement an Ad Network you must perform the following steps:
    1. Include the Ad Network Android SDK with your app and add it to the build path. Follow the
    instructions from the Ad network on how to complete this step.
    2. Create the proper “activity” and “meta-­data” tags in AndroidManifest.xml
    a. the first meta-­data tag instructs the SDK about how to find the API_KEY
    b. the second meta-­data tag instructs the SDK whether to request test ads
    3. Add your API_KEY in strings.xml
```

Does it mean i need to have api keys for each ad network like adMob,JumpTap,Mobclix and InMobi.?

or the same api key provided by flurry mediation?

I am confused,if we need to have keys of each ad network with their sdk then what is the use of flurry mediation?

can anyone please explain me?

sorry for my English.

Answer (score 1):

Just paste this in your manifest

```
<activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
           android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
```

And in your layout file

```
<com.google.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="Your app ID"
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
     android:layout_below="@+id/advertRl"
    ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR, TEST_DEVICE_ID"
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

For displaying ad you need to have appId which is available on admob.com in the manage settings.

Comment: you mean i can receive add from these networks using flurry but to show that i need to put key for that particular ad network(say admob) in my manifest?

Comment: You can add that addId in manifest or in xml file in which you wants to display ads..

Comment: if you have already implement it,can you pls share your manifest.xml and strings.xml?